# Trying to create 3x password checker (using buttons and GUI)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Im having problems creating a GUI. I want to make a program that allows users to enter their password through buttons, and it takes 3 chances before the GUI closes. I have attempted a few different methods but cannot get it to fully work.

JTextField1 is where the instructions are shown.
JTextField2 is where the password is input (correct password should be 1234)

After putting in the wrong password for the 3rd time I want it to shut.

I think the issue is that it is taking the same password 3 times and will automatically end, but I am not sure how to fix or loop properly as I am quite new to java and gui's.

This is what I have so far:

```
    final String PASSWORD = "1234";
    int attempts = 3;
    String password = "";
    while (attempts-- > 0 && !PASSWORD.equals(password)) 
    {
        jTextField1.setText("Enter your password");
        password = jTextField2.getText();
        if (password.equals(PASSWORD)) 
            jTextField1.setText("Welcome ");
        else 
            jTextField1.setText("Incorrect Pin, please try again");
    }
```

Comment: You should validate the password on some submit event like - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html and count the number of retries. If the number of retries is 3 then dispose the container. This is my look on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Consider these two lines:

```
jTextField1.setText("Enter your password");
password = jTextField2.getText();
```

The second line executes *immediately* after the first line.  There is no code here which waits for the user to type anything.

Graphical user interfaces are event-based.  A program must respond to events based on user behavior.  It is not possible to handle GUI interactions a single sequential function.

You respond to events in Java by adding an *event listener* to an object which is capable of generating certain kinds of events.  A JTextField fires an action event when the user presses Enter while it has focus.  JButtons fire an action event when activated (by user doing a mouse press and release inside it, or by the user pressing space while it has focus).

You want to add an ActionListener only once, typically right after you create the component to which it will be added.  Since the ActionListener is a separate method, you will need to keep track of your `attempts` in an instance field:

```
private static final String PASSWORD = "1234";

private int attempts = 3;

// ...

private void buildWindow() {
    // ...

    jTextField2 = new JTextField(20);
    jTextField2.addActionListener(e -> checkPassword());

    // ...
}

private void checkPassword() {
    if (password.equals(PASSWORD)) {
        jTextField1.setText("Welcome ");
    } else if (--attempts > 0) {
        jTextField1.setText("Incorrect Pin, please try again");
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```